# Sum values based on a condition in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
plots <- data.frame(plot=c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"), 
                   value= c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3))


 plot value
1  A    1     
2  A    1
3  A    1
4  B    2
5  B    2
6  C    3
7  C    3
8  C    3
```

I want to have a third column `sum` where I would sum all the values from the same plots, so it would look like this:

```
 plot value sum
1  A    1    3   
2  A    1    3
3  A    1    3
4  B    2    4
5  B    2    4
6  C    3    9
7  C    3    9
8  C    3    9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> ave(plots$value,plots$plot,FUN=sum)
[1] 3 3 3 4 4 9 9 9
```

Comment: Doesn't work on my code, I thought about using an if statement but I don't know how to set it up. I basically wanna sum up the values of the same plots. So in the case of the example I gave, I want a third columns that sums up all the values with the same plot.

Comment: @starski What doesn't work? I used it on the code you provided and it works. Did you save the output into a column?

Comment: My bad! It worked out.

Answer (score 2):

With tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
plots %>% as_tibble() %>% group_by(plot) %>% mutate(sum=sum(value))
```

returns:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 3
# Groups:   plot [3]
  plot  value   sum
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         1     3
2 A         1     3
3 A         1     3
4 B         2     4
5 B         2     4
6 C         3     9
7 C         3     9
8 C         3     9
```

Answer (score -1):

```
plots%>%group_by(plot)%>%summarise(n=sum(value),plot,.groups="drop")%>%as.data.frame()

  plot n
1    A 3
2    A 3
3    A 3
4    B 4
5    B 4
6    C 9
7    C 9
8    C 9
```

Comment: Hello ALİ, the question author has indicated that they want the output to have the same number of rows as the input. Thus, `mutate` should be used. To low quality answer reviewers: this answer is clearly *technically incorrect* but it also clearly attempts to answer the question asked.